# How to match two lines at once in vim

Tags: vim, regular-expression, vi, vi-mode

I have a file that contains records with tab separated format but in two lines, I want to arrange records in one line with tab separated values using vim editor pattern match.

Ex.

```
Abc     PQR     XYZ     NMW
    XYX     PQR     LMW
PLX     PXQ     LPN     PWF
    XYQ     PLP     PMQ    LWP
```

I want to add each second line of the record to the first line of records. The output format that I want is like this.

```
Abc     PQR     XYZ     NMW    XYX     PQR     LMW
PLX     PXQ     LPN     PWF    XYQ     PLP     PMQ     LWP
```

I tried the following command to solve my problem.

```
:%s/\n(\w\+.*)/\t\1/cgi
```

This is replacing each line data with tab at front except first line.

How can we solve this using vim pattern match and replace?

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
:%s/\n\s\+/\t/gc
```

That will find any newline character that is followed by white space and replace all of it with a tab thereby combining your lines.

Comment: If it worked don't forget to mark this as the correct answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you know the first line will always start with a letter and the second line will always start with a tab, the most vimmy way to do this would probably be to use `:g` (run an ex command on all lines matching a regex) and `j!` (join without removing whitespace). Check out `help :g` and `help :j`. Combining these, you'd get

```
:%g/^\w/j!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with `paste`:

```
paste -sd'\0\n' file
```

In `vim`:

```
:%!paste -sd'\0\n' -
```